# how can i reduce the lines of code which are under different conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

snippet is  as below:

```
@api.route('/<graphType>/<fieldType>')
def display1(graphType,fieldType):
    dbconnection = dbconnector.configuration('farmautomation')
    if graphType == "line" and fieldType == "weather details":
        dataframe_name = DataFrame_Conversion.weather_details_dataFrame(dbconnection)
        groupbyvalue = 'village'
        fieldstoaggregate = 'humidity'
        datamin, datamax = Groupby.groupby(dataframe_name, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate,
                                           field='humidity')
        return Graphs.weather(datamin, datamax)

    elif graphType == "pie" and fieldType == "total farmers":
        dataframe_name = DataFrame_Conversion.logins_time_dataFrame(dbconnection)
        groupbyvalue = 'created_time'
        fieldstoaggregate = 'count'
        result = Groupby.groupby(dataframe_name, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate,
                             field='logins')
        return Graphs.pie(result)
    elif graphType == "bar" and fieldType == "logins":
        dataframe_name = DataFrame_Conversion.logins_time_dataFrame(dbconnection)
        groupbyvalue = 'created_time'
        fieldstoaggregate = 'count'
        result = Groupby.groupby(dataframe_name, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate,
                                 field='logins')
        return Graphs.bar(result)
```

The code inside both the condition's(elif's) are same but have different return type, is there a possibility to reduce my code?

I have got no idea to try someway, any help is appreciated

Comment: @dmitryro can you please put up as an answer? still got stuck mate!!

Comment: your current code does not return anything on 2nd branch of the conditional

Comment: sorry, i missed it !!, thanks i will update

Comment: Can you have that conditional in more than one place within your application?

Comment: you mean putting those conditions outside of routes?

Comment: I mean: could those conditionals be applied/occurred in different places of the application (not just in a single route handler)?

Comment: No, Not actually ,In my case user selects graphtype and field type and if they match the condition goes on,.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the 2nd and 3rd conditions are essentially the same, so they could be combined as such:

```
@api.route('/<graphType>/<fieldType>')
def display1(graphType,fieldType):
    dbconnection = dbconnector.configuration('farmautomation')
    if graphType == "line" and fieldType == "weather details":
        dataframe_name = DataFrame_Conversion.weather_details_dataFrame(dbconnection)
        groupbyvalue = 'village'
        fieldstoaggregate = 'humidity'
        datamin, datamax = Groupby.groupby(dataframe_name, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate,
                                           field='humidity')
        return Graphs.weather(datamin, datamax)

    elif graphType in ['pie','bar'] and fieldType in ['logins','total farmers']:
        dataframe_name = DataFrame_Conversion.logins_time_dataFrame(dbconnection)
        groupbyvalue = 'created_time'
        fieldstoaggregate = 'count'
        result = Groupby.groupby(dataframe_name, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate,
                             field='logins')
        if graphType == 'pie':
            return Graphs.pie(result)
        else:
            return Graphs.bar(result)
```

There might be a better way yet to refactor, but it depends on if you have more (lots of) cases to test or just these few.

**EDIT1:** Fixed `total farmers` string

**EDIT2:** Based on additional comment/question about lots of paths, added another structure that might work.

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to Python and this code has not been tested, but the general idea is to consolidate the unbounded parts of your problem to a single spot - in this case a Dictionary - so that you have a single source of truth for that part.

```
@api.route('/<graphType>/<fieldType>')
def display1(graphType,fieldType):
    # Open your db connection
    dbconnection = dbconnector.configuration('farmautomation')
    # Get your chart data based on selection
    chart_args = get_aggregate_data(fieldType, dbconnection)
    # Try to get a chart with that data
    chart = get_chart(graphType, chart_args)

    if chart != None:
      return chart
    else:
      # Throw an error, return None - your callable
      pass


class AggregationSettings:
  def __init__(self, df_name='', group_by='',
       fields_to_agg='', over_field=''):
    self.df_name = df_name
    self.group_by = group_by
    self.fields_to_agg = fields_to_agg
    self.over_field = over_field

# This dictionary is what will grow as you add routes
DATAFRAME_TRANSLATE = {
  "weather details":AggregationSettings("weather_details","village","humidity","humidity"),
  "logins":AggregationSettings("logins_time","created_time","count","logins"),
  "total farmers":AggregationSettings("logins_time","created_time","count","logins")
}

def get_aggregate_data(fieldType, db_connection):
  agg_setting = DATAFRAME_TRANSLATE.get(fieldType, None)
  if agg_setting == None:
    # not in the dict
    raise ValueError('The specified fieldType is not valid')

  df_val = agg_setting.df_name + '_dataFrame'
  # NOTE: I'm not familiar with pandas (which I think this is), but I 
  # suspect there is a way for you to get your return value passing the
  # name, not the class explicitly.  If not, there are ways around that too
  dataframe_name = DataFrame_Conversion.get_by_name(df_val, db_connection)
  return Groupby.groupby(dataframe_name, agg_setting.group_by,
                        agg_setting.fields_to_agg, agg_setting.over_field)

def get_chart(graphType, chart_args):
  # I expect the number of charts is small(ish) and bounded,
  # so just use if/else hex
  if graphType == 'pie':
    return Graphs.pie(chart_args)
  elif graphType == 'bar':
    return Graphs.bar(chart_args)
  else:
    # handle other cases as needed...
    pass

  raise ValueError('The specified graphType is not valid')
```

Comment: only change to this answer is, fieldType in ['logins','total farmers'], thanks @Mikah Barnett

Comment: Sorry, was doing it quickly and mis-typed the literal, fixed now.

Comment: Is this a better approach, i mean writing conditions , because if there are like 100 cases?

Comment: @Codenewbie I added another section that is how I would approach building something that could handle something like 100 route combos.  I'm not an expert, but I think this would get you to a more stable, maintainable bit of code.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for all the above idea ,One thing I want to mention is, end user selects the graphType and fieldType and if the combination matches then perform whole set of operations. But now I changed it as, user selects the graphName and then based on name the operations goes on!!

Comment: Here I mentioned field='somevalue' just to differentiate in Groupby.groupby class Groupby():

    def groupby(dataframe_name, groupbyvalue, fieldstoaggregate,field):
        if field=='humidity':
            datamin = dataframe_name.loc[dataframe_name.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmin()]  
            datamax = dataframe_name.loc[dataframe_name.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmax()]
            return (datamin,datamax)